# Probability of the horse winning, given the chance of rain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, word-problem

Here's the question:

> In the past two racing seasons Seahorse has won 55% of the time if the track is 
>      dry. On rainy days when the track is muddy he won only 30% of the time. For the
>    next race day there is a 40% chance of rain. What is the probability that
>    Seahorse will win the next race?

This what I attempted:

$$
P(Dry) = \frac{55}{100} = \frac{11}{20}\\
P(Muddy) = \frac{30}{100}=\frac{3}{10}\\
P(Rain) = \frac{40}{100} = \frac{2}{5}
$$

Since $P(Muddy)$ and $P(Rain)$ are dependent events, I did the following:

$$
P(Muddy ∩ Rain) = \frac{3}{10} \times \frac{2}{5} = \frac{3}{25}
$$

Does anybody know if I'm right or am I totally on the wrong "track"?

Comment: Not enough information given.  What about if it rains a lot one day and the next day, the track is still muddy but it doesn't rain that day?  We have no previous statistics on that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read the question, rainy days are *exactly* the days on which the track is muddy, so there shouldn't be two separate probabilities for that.

$$P(\text{win}) = P(\text{rain})\cdot P(\text{win given rain})+P(\text{no rain})\cdot P(\text{win given no rain})$$

$$P(\text{win}) = 0.4 \cdot 0.3 + 0.6 \cdot 0.55 = \boxed{0.45}=\frac{9}{20}$$

Comment: My reading of the question is that $P(dry)$ is the probability of winning on a dry track, $P(muddy)$ the probability of winning on a muddy track, and $P(rain)$ the chance of the next day being rainy.  In which case he did the first half of your $P(win)$ equation.

Answer (score 2):

You are sort of on the right track but you have run only half the race.  You also have to add the probability of winning of a driy track which is 
$$
\frac{11}{20} \times \frac{3}{5} == 0.33
$$

Another helpful hint:  $\frac{30}{100}$ is not quite $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Where are you getting 3/5 from?

Comment: @ub3rst4r it's $1-\frac25$ - the probability that there _isn't_ rain.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity it is best to simply identify the two events as simply Winning and Raining.   Don't muddy the waters by giving the conditional events confusing names.   Always label things as clearly as possible, because it then often becomes obvious what you need to do.

For brevity let's use $W$ for Wins and $R$ for Rains (and $\neg R$ for not rains).

> In the past two racing seasons Seahorse has won 55% of the time if the track is 
>    dry.

This is the conditional probability that Seahorse wins when it does not rain.

$$\mathsf P(W\mid \neg R) = 55\%$$

> On rainy days when the track is muddy he has won only 30% of the time.

This is the conditional probability of winning when it rains:

$$\mathsf P(W\mid R) = 30\%$$

> For the next race day there is a 40% chance of rain.

This is what it sais:

$$\mathsf P(R) = 40\%$$

> What is the probability that Seahorse will win the next race?

This is obtained by using the **Law of Total Probability**:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(W) & = \mathsf P(W\mid\neg R)\mathsf P(\neg R)+\mathsf P(W\mid R)\mathsf P(R)
\\ & = 0.55\times(1-0.40) + 0.30\times 0.40
\\ & =
\end{align}$$

Comment: "don't muddy the waters" my gosh the puns :)